# How can I add audio call to rocket chat

Tags: chat, rocket.chat

I installed rocket chat on my server and now I need to install some app, that will allowed me to call. So, I tried to install `jitsi`, but it doesn't work on my 3d domain (`meet.myurl.com, rocket chat is working on myurl.com`) and now I tried to install `WebRTC`, but it doesn't work for me. I haven't any notification, when I call. On mobile version I haven't some button to call. I don't know need I do some configuration with my server? I didn't find any documentation. Or may be someone know some easy variant to do voice call in rocketchat? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case. I just turned it on as in the picture. And video calls became possible on Android and Web-browser clients. There is no need to restart the server.

- Server on Docker
- Version   3.2.0-develop
- PID   1
- Running Instances 1
- OpLog Enabled
- Branch    HEAD
- Tag   3.1.2
- OS Platform   linux
- OS Release    3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64
- Node Version  v12.16.1
- Mongo Version 4.0.18

[image: In my case. I just turned it on as in the picture. And video calls became possible. There is no need to restart the server.]

Comment: Worked for me only when I selected "Always open in New Windows" for some reason.